# Scrolling past the end in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to enable being able to scroll past the last line in IntelliJ IDEA?

It's a nice feature that exists in some editors, as it lets you keep your eyes at the middle of the screen, rather than have to stare at the bottom of it

Is there any way to enable something like this? Either through the standard settings or via plugin?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`File` **->** `Settings` **->** `Editor` **->** `General` **->** Check `Show virtual space at file bottom`

Answer (score 13):

**Mac:** `IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Check: Show virtual space at file bottom`

**PC:** `File -> Settings -> Editor -> Check: Show virtual space at file bottom`

Answer (score 4):

**Short way**:
You could also hit **shift key** twice to open menu and write "show virtual space" and then just click on the option to toggle it **on/off**.
[image]